# Terraform: Using conditional on nested loops

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, terraform

I have the following expression

```
flatten(
        [
          for region in local.customers: [
            for customer in region: [
              customer.customer_code if length(regexall("foo", customer.name)) == 0 && length(regexall("bar", customer.name)) == 0
            ]
          ]
        ]
      )
```

I am getting the error

```
The Terraform configuration must be valid before initialization so that
Terraform can determine which modules and providers need to be installed.
╷
│ Error: Missing item separator
│ 
│ On alerts.tf line 34: Expected a comma to mark the beginning of the next
│ item.
```

I cannot really find the right syntax here...
This expression works perfectly

```
[for c in local.customers["a_region"] : c.name if length(regexall("foo", c.name)) == 0 && length(regexall("bar", c.name)) == 0]
```

which makes me think that there is no error with the conditional. Once I apply the same logic in a nested loop with a `flatten` it break.

What do you think the problem is here?

Comment: What exactly is `local.customers`?

Answer (score 1):

I think the last pair of `[]` brackets is redundant:

```
flatten(
    [
      for region in local.customers: [
        for customer in region:
          customer.customer_code if length(regexall("foo", customer.name)) == 0 && length(regexall("bar", customer.name)) == 0
      ]
    ]
  )
```

Comment: This works indeed!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in the end

```
jsonencode(
      flatten(
        [
          for region in local.customers: [
            for customer in region: [
              customer.customer_code
            ] if length(regexall("foo", customer.name)) == 0 && length(regexall("bar", customer.name)) == 0
          ]
        ]
      )
    )
```